# Написание калькулятора

Tags: c

Мне нужно написать на Си следующее:

```
Программе поступает на ввод нечто такое:
3-2
Программа должна вывести это:
1
```

Т.е. это калькулятор, но какой!
Нельзя просить пользователя ввести знак операции или числа по отдельности.
Мои знания о программировании на Си невелики. (Мягко говоря, я новичок)

Какую литературу мне нужно почитать для выполнения этого задания?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser думаю этого хватит...

Comment: Например, [Книгу Дракона](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B:_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B,_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B)?

Comment: @VladD ну это уже жёстко...

Comment: @pavel: Зато подобные вопросы отсеет раз и навсегда.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/svn.html вот тут ещё можно посмотреть (ну после того как скачать имею ввиду)

Comment: @pavel В книге Дракона эта задача решена чуть ли не в первой главе, причём там же приведён код на языке Си.

Comment: Поищи как infix calculator. [Например](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696085/infix-calculator).

Answer (score 6):

Для разбора сложных арифметических выражений Вам может помочь [обратная польская нотация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C). Статей и объяснений по этой теме достаточно, например, [тык сюда](https://habrahabr.ru/post/282379/). Но для её использования Вам необходимо будет работать со стеком.

PS По условию не совсем понятно, насколько сложным может быть выражение, т.к. пример приведён всего лишь с двумя операндами.

Comment: Выражение может быть очень сложным.
2 - 3 (3 * 7) + 3 
и так до бесконечности. (не лимитировано кол-во чисел)

Comment: Тут уж все равно. Сложность здесь определяется количеством операций (похоже, у Вас базовые 4 операции + скобки?).